# Regular expression in R - Extract Word

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have the following text:

text='have a nice day, @hello, mr burs'

How can I extract only the @hello from the sentence with regular expressions in R?

Comment: what have you tried? please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Start here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

One option uses `gsub`:

```
text <- 'have a nice day, @hello, mr burs'
x <- gsub('.*(@\\w+).*', '\\1', text)
x

[1] "@hello"
```

### Demo

Comment: `str_extract` is a good choice as well:  
`stringr::str_extract(text,'@\\w+')`